# Efficient fenceposting of 1D ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most efficient way to reshape `data` to `fencepost` with `numpy`?

```
data      = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])                                                             
fencepost = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same result simply by looking at the same data differently:

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> fencepost = as_strided(data, shape=(data.shape[0]-1, 2),
                           strides=(data.strides[0],)*2)
>>> fencepost
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

No data is being copied, so especially for very large arrays, this is going to be about as quick as it gets. And if you do need a separate copy, you can simply do `fencepost = fencepost.copy()` and let numpy handle everything internally for you:

```
In [11]: data = np.arange(10000000)

In [12]: %timeit as_strided(data, shape=(data.shape[0]-1, 2),
...                         strides=(data.strides[0],)*2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit as_strided(data, shape=(data.shape[0]-1, 2),
...                         strides=(data.strides[0],)*2).copy()
10 loops, best of 3: 183 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really reshaping, because the second array has a different number of elements.  If the first array has N elements (in this case N=5) the second has 2N-2 (in this case 8).

So you will have to make a new array and populate it accordingly.  There are two approaches to this.  You can populate column by column, or row by row.  Which is more efficient will depend on ... well lets find out!

Here I use %timeit from IPython with three different array sizes:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

data      = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])                                                             
#fencepost = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])

def fp1(data):
    f = np.zeros((data.shape[0]-1,2))

    for i in range(data.shape[0]-1):
        f[i] = data[i:i+2]

    return f

def fp2(data):
    f = np.zeros((data.shape[0]-1,2))

    f[:,0] = data[:-1]
    f[:,1] = data[1:]

    return f

%timeit fp1(data)
%timeit fp2(data)

data2 = np.array(range(100000))
%timeit fp1(data2)
%timeit fp2(data2)

data3 = np.array(range(10000000))
%timeit fp1(data3)
%timeit fp2(data3)
```

On my computer the results are slightly more efficient to do row by row for small arrays, but quickly column by column is much, much better (hence fp2 is the efficient answer):

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 13 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.4 µs per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 203 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 20.7 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 253 ms per loop
```

Essentially, fp2 is faster because it is only 2 numpy operations, whereas fp1 is a loop requiring many calls to numpy.  For small arrays, the overhead of 5 calls to numpy is negligible.